# NodsJs: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unscoped')

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to fetch the leaves count from leaves table by using `sequelize` but it gives me error of undefined (reading 'unscoped'). I am using postgresql and NodeJS.

**here is my query**

```
router.get('/:userId', checkToken, authorize(), async (req, res) => {
try {
        const { params } = req;
        const { userId } = params;
 const leaveCounts = await db.leaves.unscoped().findAll({
            attributes: [[db.Sequelize.literal('SELECT count(distinct(id)) from leaves'), 'leaveCount']],
            where: {
                "userId": {
                    userId
                }
            },
            raw: true
        });
const data = {
            
            leaveCounts

        }

        res.status(200).json({
            data
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("error in status: ", e)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Internal Server Error",
            status: false,
        })
    }
})

export default router;
```

**error:**

```
error in status:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unscoped')
```

**Postman response:**

```
{
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": false
}
```

please help how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leaves` property in `db` object may be `undefined`.
Check the type of `db.leaves`

ex) `console.log(typeof db.leaves)`